# Check a key value from a list of dictionaries of lists of dictionaries against separate list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im trying to loop around a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing a list of sub-dictionaries. I want to match each of these sub-dictionary keys to a value in my 'mps' list, which currently contains two author_ids that are also present in the sub-dictionary payload.

The keys in the main dictionary iterate as such: ['data', 'meta', 'data', 'meta', 'title', 'detail', 'type', 'status'].

```
def mp_list6(List, mps):
p = []
for mp_dict in List:
    a=0
    try:
        for subDict in mp_dict["data"]:
            if subDict["author_id"] in mps:
                a+=1
                p.append(a)
    except KeyError:
        if subDict["author_id"] in mps:
            a=1
            p.append(a)
            return p
```

The output is a list of integers: [1,2,3....94,1,2,3...155,1]
Ideally it would be 249. Ive also tried a defaultdict to show the values of the author ids but to no success.

I have posted screenshots of payloads 1,2, and 3 below being the start, middle and end payload screenshots respectively.[payload1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41tf6.png) [payload2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bf1o.png) [payload3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOCpr.png)

Comment: Can you add a couple of key-value pairs of the dictionary as text so we can reproduce what you're doing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand it right you are looping one depth to much into List

```
    def mp_list(List, mps):
        p=[]
        for mp_dict in List:
            helper=0
            for subDict in mp_dict["data"]:
                if subDict["author_id"] in mps:
                    helper+=1
            p.append(helper)
```

This should reduce the Code for three nested forloops.
Also in your Code you are resetting p in every iteration
of the first for loop i fixed that

Comment: Thank you, but I get: "keyError: 'data' ... I want to add that in the List is an additional dictionary embedded after each key = 'data' dictionary, called 'meta' -> so the structure is: [{'data':[ list of dictionaries}], 'meta': {{}}, 'data':[list of dictionaries}], 'meta':{{}}....etc].

Comment: Sry but this is too less information update your Question with a better representation, or with an Screenshot of the Error Message. Your Data Structure is also completely wrong you mixed up [ and }

Comment: Apologies. The code from jack works now, but it is only outputting '94', as  the number of tweets from a single 'mps'. 94 is the number of tweets in the last string of mps. Ive tried appending each p value to a list but it will not work. Also, I cant edit the question as it keeps saying 'your post appears to contain code' etc. thanks

Comment: Do you want for every entry in mp_dict a different p Value? or do you want the total p Value of everything like now? Or do you want to use different p Values for different mps Lists?

Comment: every entry in mp_dict a different p value thanks

Comment: i get a key error = 'data'. 
Im trying to edit my question with the payload but the platform wont let me